# Using Ctrl+[0-9] to cycle between windows using tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I have started using `tmux` but I feel that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>0-9</kbd> is very annoying, because it's used so often.

How do I bind the keyboard so I only need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0-9</kbd> for changing windows (like in Chrome)?

I have tried to configure it in the `.tmux.conf`, but without any success.

this is my current .tmux.conf file

```
bind C select-pane -t :.+
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
```

Comment: The shortcuts are as simple as explained, Ctrl+[1-9] for tab [1-9]. The difference between them is that it currently does not work, and 'bind C select-pane -t :.+' was just something i tried out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several of the Control+digit keystrokes generate fairly standardized sequences, but not all of them do.

Here is what I found in the *xterm* that I had handy:

```
C-1: 1  (i.e. not different form a plain 1 keystroke)
C-2: ^@
C-3: ^[
C-4: ^\
C-5: ^]
C-6: ^^
C-7: ^_
C-8: ^?
C-9: 9  (i.e. plain 9)
C-0: 0  (i.e. plain 0)
```

The same sequences are generated in *iTerm* 2 (although this is highly configurable).

If your terminal emulator generates similar sequences, then you *could* bind most of them (though you need to use the standard, non-numeric “names” for the keys, e.g. `C-@` or `^@`, et cetera). You will have to find a way to configure your terminal to send some kind of sequence for any keystrokes that do not already send something different from the unmodified key (i.e. like 1, 9, and 0 above).

*However*, binding these keys without a Prefix (`bind -n …`) will probably break lots of stuff. Specifically, `^[` is the Escape character (used in almost all terminal control sequences), `^?` is usually the Delete character, `^@` (as C-Space) is commonly used in Emacs(-style) editing, et cetera.

Probably a better approach is to configure your terminal to send the xterm-style “modifyOtherKeys” sequences that *tmux* 1.8 recognizes (if your *xterm* supports this, *tmux* automatically asks for this to happen):

```
C-1: ^[[27;5;49~
C-2: ^[[27;5;50~
C-3: ^[[27;5;51~
C-4: ^[[27;5;52~
C-5: ^[[27;5;53~
C-6: ^[[27;5;54~
C-7: ^[[27;5;55~
C-8: ^[[27;5;56~
C-9: ^[[27;5;57~
C-0: ^[[27;5;48~
```

The *tmux* names for these keys are exactly `C-0`, et cetera.

Note: These key names and sequences are not recognized by *tmux* versions older than 1.8.

You would bind them like this (in your `.tmux.conf`):

```
bind-key -n C-0 select-window -t :0
bind-key -n C-1 select-window -t :1
bind-key -n C-2 select-window -t :2
bind-key -n C-3 select-window -t :3
bind-key -n C-4 select-window -t :4
bind-key -n C-5 select-window -t :5
bind-key -n C-6 select-window -t :6
bind-key -n C-7 select-window -t :7
bind-key -n C-8 select-window -t :8
bind-key -n C-9 select-window -t :9
```

Comment: "if your xterm supports this, tmux automatically asks for this to happen" - could you briefly elaborate/mention the mechanism by which tmux accomplishes this?

Comment: @Charles: *tmux* 1.8 sends the sequence `^[[>4;1m` to enable the modifyOtherKeys functionality (see [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), search for *modifyOtherKeys*). However, *tmux* 1.9 [no longer send this sequence](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/f52eac62259c431daac84ddb6c2a5b7ebd528c2c/).

Answer (score 3):

@ChrisJohnsen answer is perfect, however some people might want some help on how to setup [Iterm 2](https://www.iterm2.com) keys in order to achieve this behavior.

First, go to "Iterm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Keys" as in:

[image: Iterm profile configuration]

and then click on `+` symbol to add preset when some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> is not on the list (the format on the list will be `^number`), as it is the case for the `^1`, which is not available on the default list.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> when selecting the keyboard shortcut and select "send escape sequence" as action. Then, add Chris Johnsen's escape sequences without the ^[, which will be added by the iterm2 action:

[image]

Later, repeat this procedure for all other control keys, editing those already existent.