# How to debug what blocks a key sequence in urxvt?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, urxvt

According to [this port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96884/using-ctrl0-9-to-cycle-between-windows-using-tmux?newreg=2df63577f0484f8080a5d51bd4bf1cbc), i made these configuration in my .Xresources for urxvt:

```
URxvt*keysym.Control-1:                \033[27;5;49~
URxvt*keysym.Control-2:                \033[27;5;50~
URxvt*keysym.Control-3:                \033[27;5;51~
URxvt*keysym.Control-4:                \033[27;5;52~
URxvt*keysym.Control-5:                \033[27;5;53~
URxvt*keysym.Control-6:                \033[27;5;54~
URxvt*keysym.Control-7:                \033[27;5;55~
URxvt*keysym.Control-8:                \033[27;5;56~
URxvt*keysym.Control-9:                \033[27;5;57~
URxvt*keysym.Control-0:                \033[27;5;48~
```

In my 'cat -v', when i press Control-1,

```
\033[27;5;49~
```

is printed as expected, so do other key combinations, except Control-5.
When i type Control-5, nothing printed.
I really don't know what is the difference for Control-5, either how to debug this problem. Is that urxvt makes some default mapping for Control-5, at least i don't make that myself.
This is my full .Xresources:

```
URxvt*termName:                       screen-256color
URxvt*scrollBar:                      false
URxvt*scrollBar_right:                false
URxvt*urgentOnBell:                   false
URxvt*visualBell:                     false
URxvt*background:                     #2E3436
URxvt*foreground:                     #BDC3C7
URxvt*color0:                         #2E3436
URxvt*color1:                         #C0392B
URxvt*color2:                         #27AE60 
URxvt*color3:                         #F39C12
URxvt*color4:                         #3465A4
URxvt*color5:                         #75507B
URxvt*color6:                         #16A085
URxvt*color7:                         #BDC3C7
URxvt*color8:                         #555753
URxvt*color9:                         #EA6153
URxvt*color10:                        #2ECC71
URxvt*color11:                        #F1C40F
URxvt*color12:                        #729FCF
URxvt*color13:                        #AD7FA8
URxvt*color14:                        #1ABC9C
URxvt*color15:                        #FBFCFC
URxvt*colorBD:                        #BDC3C7
URxvt*font:                           xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12:style=Regular:antialias=false
URxvt*boldFont:                       xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12:style=Bold:antialias=false
URxvt*italicFont:                     xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12:style=Italic:antialias=false
URxvt*boldItalicFont:                 xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12:style=Bold Italic:antialias=false
URxvt*depth:                          32
URxvt*perl-ext-common:                default,clipboard
URxvt*iso14755:                       false
URxvt*iso14755_52:                    false
```

EDIT:
To be clear, i am using awesome titling window manager.

Answer (score 1):

urxvt don't seem to be the problem here (I'm using urxvt too). Maybe awesome blocks this key sequence.

Try to open urxvt alone (without awesome). To do this open another `tty` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>fN</kbd>) and type something like `xinit urxvt -- :1`, and try the key sequence. If this doesn't show results, try to change to sh, for example, and test again.

I was in a similar problem, time ago.